# Send Mouse Event on Login Window using Objective C

Tags: macos

Am new to Objective C, am trying to generate mouse event on LoginWindow but am unable to do so, same code works fine on normal desktop.

Following is the function am using for generating mouse event:

**CGPostMouseEvent();**

Please help me with this.

Thanks,
Paul Sudhakar.